# Inherited a Silverlight/WCF application need to fix WindowsAuthentication

Tags: wcf, silverlight, iis-7.5, windows-authentication

I've inherited a Silverlight/WCF application. (Having worked on .net MVC, and SPA for quite a while)

I tried switching the IIS website folder to see if a tweak to the code and a fresh build would work, it didn't work and I switched back and although the website is functional it has a number of faults.

For some reason the Windows authentication appears to have stopped working, this authorises a number of the admin functions. I think this is broken and so not enabling the functionality in the Silverlight app.

The server I've inherited has the applications as folders in the default website, which is new to me, and quite constraining. I've gone through IISAdmin videos, and learnt a lot, but not enough to fix the issue.

I am unable to get the software to run in VS2013, quite a bump after working on Single Page Applications.

I'm stumped as to how the same code put back no longer works; I've learnt my lesson, but I still need to fix the system. I am not sure whether IISReset would make a difference since the AppPool is recycled every 29 hours. I've found out what the harm in trying is, and so I am proceeding with caution.

So my main goal would be to get the Windows Authentication working again.

Comment: Just to check the basics: in the Solution Explorer, click the Web project, inspect the properties in the pane below and make sure that `Anonymous Authentication` is Disabled and `Windows Authentication` is Enabled.

Comment: Yes, only Windows Authentication is enabled

Comment: In IIS, you also need to make sure Windows Authentication is enabled as well.  Also, in VS2013, there is no Silverlight 4 support, it auto-upgrades it to Silverlight 5.  It is not clear how old the app you've inherited is... but if it didn't survive the upgrade, that could be giving you troubles running it locally.

Comment: Sorry. It was the IIS that I had inspected, the Web project properties only has:
- Development Server
- Misc
-- Project File
-- Project Folder

There are only two projects in it, and neither of them seem to show much in the properties section.